# Standalone Application Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have a Qt application that needs a specific folder and some files. This folder is now located inside the project folder. Is there any way to make this folder be "generated" when I use the `make` command to create the Standalone version of the program.

I was thinking about changing something in my .pro file but could not figure out any solution that way.

The folder contains some .lua code that I need to make the software work properly if the user select some functionalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that copy these resources to destination folder the binary installed via qmake. Please refer to the link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474964/qmake-command-to-copy-files-and-folders-into-output-directory)

Some answers are out-of-date but inspire enough.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution(see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html):

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = 
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
SOURCES += main.cpp

lua_dir.target = .makedir
lua_dir.commands = test -d lua_dir || mkdir lua_dir

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += lua_dir
PRE_TARGETDEPS += .makedir
```

You should replace `lua_dir.commands = test -d lua_dir || mkdir lua_dir` with appropriate to you command, I use bash command intepreter here.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can change `DESTDIR` qmake variable to compile binary file straight to specified directory.
2. you can use `INSTALLS`:

   ```
   someTarget.path = $$OUT_PWD/MyFolder
   someTarget.files = $$PWD/SomeDirToCopy/*
   INSTALLS += someTarget
   ```

   this will copy all files from `ProjectDirectory/SomeDirToCopy` folder to `BuildDirecory/MyFolder` after you run `make install` in build directory.